# CORS issue - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, cors, okta

I am working on reactjs frontend with is using a spring boot in backend. 
I am trying to calling the end point from frontend as follows :

```
testOktaTokenAtRest(data) {
  var oauth=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('okta-token-storage'))
  console.log("toekn is: ==>  "+oauth.accessToken.tokenType + 
  oauth.accessToken.accessToken)
  console.log("toekn received from action is inside this obj: ",data)
  var searchCriteria = JSON.stringify(data.data)
  console.log("searchCriteria data -------: " , searchCriteria)

 let _headerForSearch={
    auth : 'Bearer ' + oauth.accessToken.accessToken 
  }
  $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/ckcapp/api/posttest",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data:searchCriteria,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", _headerForSearch.auth);
    },
    success: function(response) {

      console.log("response from okta enabled get api is: ",response)
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log("error from okta enabled get api is: ",xhr.responseText 
     + " " +status + " " + error );
    }
  });


  }
```

When i make request, i get the following error :-

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:8000/ckcapp/api/posttest' 
>       from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
>       response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
>       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
>       resource.

My spring-boot application has following configuration:

```
CORSFilter
    public class CORSFilter implements Filter {


    private static final String ONE_HOUR = "3600";

      @Override
      public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException 
    {
      }

      @Override
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, 
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
    "http://localhost:3000");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, 
    GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", ONE_HOUR);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", 
    "authorization,content-type");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested- 
    With,Origin,Content-Type, Accept, x-device-user-agent, Content-Type");

        if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
           HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) 
    req;
           if (httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ORIGIN) != null
              && 
      httpServletRequest.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name())
              && 
    httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD) 
    != 
    null) {

              return;
           }
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
      }

      @Override
      public void destroy() {
      } 
    }
```

and my i am calling the endpoint as :

```
 @RestController
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    public class CkcOktaController {
        @PostMapping("/api/posttest")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_email')")
    public String setString(@RequestBody CustomerDetailsNew 
        customerDetails) {
        System.out.println("In post method ");
        System.out.println("text :" + customerDetails.toString());
        System.out.println("text :" + customerDetails.getEntityId());
        return "Success";
    }
    }
```

I think I am missing some configuration.

The application is protected by OKTA.

Comment: I think you need to handle the preflight requests 
 .https://blog.morethancode.dev/killing-cors-preflight-requests-on-a-react-spa/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using React with Spring JWT faced similar issue as blocked by CORS policy   .

added `http.cors()` in my SecurityConfigurer class to resolve

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().......
    }
}
```

### controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000"})
@RestController
```

Comment: Tried various different solutions suggested in different threads. But this is the only one that helped me. Thank you!

Comment: This took quite some time to figure this out, thank you! I understand CSRF should be implemented, but that comes a little later for us.
Can confirm that this is also a thing after the Spring 3.0 changes where WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated in favour of the SecurityFilterChain approach.

Answer (score 11):

I usually use a bean to configure my CORS settings. This is from a [recent blog post](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/22/java-microservices-spring-boot-spring-cloud):

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> simpleCorsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: This filter based config worked perfectly well for me. 
Can someone help me understand, why another configuration i.e adding `@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 @Override
 public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {  registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
 }
}` didn't work? This approach is suggested in most of the related discussion but didn't work for me.

Comment: When I tried this, I encountered the following:

_java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*" since that cannot be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead._

Comment: With the latest version of Spring Boot, you have to use `allowedOriginPatterns("*")` if you want wildcard support. Or define things explicitly with `allowedPatterns()`. You can also define in YAML, for example: `allowed-origins: "http://localhost:8100,http://localhost:9000"`